# Spring Data JPA - findByAlias vs. findUserByAlias - error with both

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am using spring boot 2 with JPA and Spring Security.

I have a handler method that, depending upon a dropdown, will find all links either similar to a specific title or posted by a specific user.  I know my database is set up properly.

I am getting a null pointer exception at this line:

```
Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByAlias("searchTerm");
```

I have tried changing the method to findByAlias(...) with the same result.

This is the code for my UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> findUserByAlias(String alias);

    Optional<User> findByAlias(String alias);
}
```

and this is my handler method wherein the error occurs at this line:

```
Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByAlias("searchTerm");
```

```
 @GetMapping("/search")
    public String showSearchResults(@RequestParam("searchTerm") String searchTerm, @RequestParam("searchBy") String searchBy, Model model) {
        System.out.println("INSIDE showSearchResults + searchTerm =" + searchTerm);
        List<Link> searchResults;

        if(searchBy.equals("user")) {
            System.out.println("INSIDE IF EQUALS 'user'");
            // get the user by alias
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findUserByAlias("searchTerm");
            // if the user is present the find all links by the user id
            if (user.isPresent()) {
                searchResults = linkRepository.findAllByUser_Id(user.get().getId());
            } else {
                searchResults = null;
            }
        }

        if(searchBy.equals("title")){
                searchResults = linkRepository.findAllByTitleLike("%" + searchTerm + "%");
        } else {
            searchResults = null;
        }

        model.addAttribute("searchTerm", new SearchTerm());
        model.addAttribute("searchResults", searchResults);

        return "search-results";
    }
```

and this is my User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String email;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private boolean enabled;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();


    @Column
    private String firstName;

    @Column
    private String lastName;

    @Column
    private String fullName;

    @Column
    private String alias;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    public User(){

    }

    public User(String email, String password, boolean enabled,
                String firstName, String lastName,
                String fullName, String alias) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.enabled = enabled;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public void addRole(Role role){
        roles.add(role);
    }

    public void addRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        roles.forEach(this::addRole);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public String getConfirmPassword() {
        return confirmPassword;
    }

    public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
        this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Role role : roles){
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
       }
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

So I have two questions:

1.)  First and most importantly - why am I getting null pointer exception?  I'm at a loss as to how to go about debugging this.

2.) What is the difference between findByAlias and findUserByAlias?

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thank you for your help,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is your `userRepository` injected into your controller?  It seems that is the most likely reason for the null pointer.

Comment: Ah... wow...silly me I forgot to assign it in my constructor.  Thank you!

Comment: But I am still confused as to the difference between the two methods.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between the two methods.  I suspect when you get that wired in they will return the same results.

Comment: You are correct.  Not only did I forget to wire that in but I also had a logic error in the handler such that results were always made null.

Comment: I tried both methods with the same result.  They seem to function identically.